# Normalizing regressors in logistic space

Tags: logistic, clustering, regression-coefficients, normalization

I have a bunch of `sklearn` `sgd` models that have beta coefficients in the logistic space.  I want to see if these models cluster well to create new models that sufficiently represent the group.  My question is, would it be prudent to normalize the beta coefficients for the models?

Given that it's in logistic space that seems dangerous.